# How to overclock RPi 3 on Windows 10 ARM

Tags: windows, cpu, overclocking

I have an RPi3B running Windows 10 ARM (not scrappy IoT). I used [WOA Deployer RPi](https://github.com/WOA-Project/WOA-Deployer-Rpi) to burn the image into SD card. I can boot into desktop, but the system is slow & laggy.

When I looked up Task Manager I found the CPU is running at 0.60 GHz max.

But this makes no sense... When running on Raspbian, it just managed the frequency perfectly.
(And by perfectly I mean following)

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/cpuinfo_min_freq
600000
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/cpuinfo_max_freq
1200000
```

Using `sys-bench`(Still on Raspbian from `apt install sys-bench`), I was able to bench the CPU and meanwhile, I did scripts as follows:

```
while true; do
   cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/cpuinfo_cur_freq
   sleep 0.5
done
```

And the result seems good...

```
600000
600000
600000
600000
1200000
1200000
1200000
1200000
1200000
```

... Back on Windows, it just runs at 0.60 GHz (Task Manager says so), no matter how I bench it, frequency makes no change.

And I tried to find some "corresponding" things like `config.txt` (like Raspbian has in `/boot`) but no use.

So here's the problem...

1. Isn't stock max frequency 1.20 GHz? Why it is sitting just at 0.60 GHz on Windows?
   (Or actually it's the problem with Windows? If this is the case then I can really say nothing about it)
2. Is there any way to "overclock" or bring the frequency back to 1.20 GHz?

Comment: I know nothing about Windows, but it's normal for all modern processors to run slower when not under load.  This should not amount to diminished performance ("slow and laggy"), but it is also under the control of the OS. WRT overclocking, that's done by the firmware before the OS boots, so if you have boot partition w/ `config.txt` in or the equivalent you can follow the usual instructions.

Comment: I don't think there is a constructive answer to this, Windows being slow and laggy on slow CPUs was yesterday's news since circa 1995 :) Nevertheless, thanks for sharing this, I didn't know such a contraption existed. Guess we'll soon have to add `windows-10-arm` tag or something along the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this thread is now over a year old, I'm going to answer it anyway to provide help for people who see this.

You have to make sure to set arm_freq on the Boot-Partition of your SD-Card or USB Device. Most likely you need to set overvoltage to around 6-7. (config.txt)

Also, be sure to set the frequency in the UEFI too, pressing escape during boot time. Go to Device Settings -> Raspberry Configuration. I was able to overclock to 2.1 GHz, you probably then want to add a cooling solution (like a fan or heat sink).